# Generate random number in Source XAML-attribute of Image

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

As a part of a Windows application (that I had to take over) I have the following line in a XAML file:

```
<Image Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="5" 
  x:Name="PART_batterySymbol"
  Stretch="Fill" 
  Source="/CustomControls;component/Resources/Symbol_Battery_2_50x50.png"/>
```

It shows a battery icon in a ListBox row:

[image: screenshot]

Is it please possible to have a source code *inside of XAML* which would randomly select between the 3 images I have?

- Symbol_Battery_1_50x50.png
- Symbol_Battery_2_50x50.png
- Symbol_Battery_3_50x50.png

I am a newbie in WPF and C#, but I had some developing experience with Adobe/Apache Flex and there it was possible to embed some code *inside of MXML* files by using `{ .... }` brackets

Comment: So using a converter is not an option for you? By default you cannot put code directly inside xaml, nor should you ever do this.

Comment: I've unsuccessfully tried Source="Symbol_Battery_`<![CDATA[ 2 ]]>`_50x50.png"... What is a "converter"?

Comment: `Is it please possible to have a source code inside of XAML which would randomly select between the 3 images I have?`
What do you mean by `source code inside of XAML` exactly?
"Is it possible to write switching logic between multiple images in xaml without anything in code-behind?" - is that what you are asking?

Comment: I would love to switch the logic in the .cs file instead - but don't see how to access it (there are some obscure custom controls involved)...

Comment: What is the condition, upon which the images should switch?

Comment: Just random (1, 2 or 3). It is a fake Bluetooth demo

Comment: Ok, the way I see it: you can make a style for that image and make an event trigger, which will switch sources upon some event triggering. The question is, what the event will be. It might be changing of underlying data or user input event. But I see no way to do it *randomly* in xaml only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think easiest way to get what you want, especially if your image is inside deep complex tree, is this:

```
public static class BatteryIcons {
    private static readonly Random _random = new Random();
    public static ImageSource Random {
        get
        {
            var id = _random.Next(1, 4);
            // read random icon from your resources given id and return
            // alternatively, use default ImageSourceConverter
            string path = "get path to your icon";
            return (ImageSource) new ImageSourceConverter().ConvertFromString(path);
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your xaml:

```
<Image Source="{x:Static wpf:BatteryIcons.Random}" />
```

So you basically reference static property of static class, and each time this property would be called it will return random image of your battery icon.